# Weird characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems, mysql2

I am getting some weird symbols when I am inserting data into my MySQL Database.

The table is set up to use UTF8_bin. The symbols are like

```
Landon?ÇÖs
```

The ?ÇÖ is supposed to be a `'`.

I am passing all the rows for the MySQL table from a script like so:

```
insert = ("INSERT INTO #{event.split(" : ")[0]} (`Date`, `Start`, `End`, `Location`, `Details`, `Map`) VALUES (#{event.split(" : ")[1]});").to_s
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "hostInfo", :username => "usName", :password =>"usPass", :database => "dbName")
client.query(insert)
client.close
```

Also I am using the  mysql2 gem to connect and pass information to the database.

I did some digging and I got the console to give me this output by trying to replace the special char with a different char. Here is the error message that the console is outputting    incompatible character encodings: IBM437 and UTF-8
    (Encoding::CompatibilityError)

Comment: table may be utf8. what about the ruby->db connection? what about the ruby->output environment? doesn't help to have utf8 text if you dump it into a (say) iso8859 display system.

Comment: Marc, the db connection is set up just with the default encoding. Im not 100% sure what the output encoding is but the information that is being handled is not being displayed for the user to be seen as far as on the console side.

Comment: so the chars are showing up `?ÇÖ` in the table itself? make sure that whatever's inserting the data originally did it properly as well. the ENTIRE processing chain has to maintain the same charset throughout, or have appropriate conversion logic at the "borders".

Comment: Yeah the chars are showing up in the table itself and only in the table. If i put out the information to the command line the ' show up just fine. Do you think that I should try and do like a set char to uft8 on to the information before I pass it on? Cause right now its just set to pass the string on as a literal to the MySQL Table

Comment: Marc, I did some digging and I got the console to give me this output by trying to replace the special char with a different char. Here is the error message that the console is outputting "incompatible character encodings: IBM437 and UTF-8 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)"

Comment: Put that information into your question, where you'd have put it if you originally included it. Don't use "edited" or "updated" tags. We can see what you changed if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a MySql encoding issue. Change the table encoding to `utf8_general_ci`.